# WSO2 Usage Plans & Billing

Tags: wso2, billing

WSO2 documentation says that billing, metering is available as part of the platform. I am evaluating this platform in a stand alone mode. I would like to know

1. How can I define my own usage plans?
2. How can I define metering and billing rules?
3. Is it possible to customize the billing template?

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 1):

Subscription types and the respective limits of parameters for each of the packages are defined in 
`repository/conf/multitenancy/multitenancy-packages.xml` in Stratos_Manager. There you can define you packages ie Demo,SMB,Professional ect and you can define your own usage plans using this configuration.

The billing and metering rules are defined in `multitenancy-billing-rules.drl` and `throttling-rules.drl` also located in Stratos_Manager, repository/conf folder.These rules are defined using drools. There you can define metering and billing rules.

You can  further configure billing by editing `billing-config.xml`. Hope this clarifies your questions on billing configurations.

And also no it is not possible to customize the billing template..

Regards

Amani